# Computing a ranking with Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java-8, java-stream

A common problem when processing data is to build a ranking of items
based on some property.

The [ranking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking) operation consists 
in mapping the items to a set of ordinal numbers (called ranking).
In presence of *ties* (i.e. two items having the same ranking) several
strategies can be used, in this context we will assume the standard competition ranking (a.k.a. *"1224" ranking*) is used.

The question I'd like to investigate here is what is the "*best*" way
of doing this using the streaming API. Where best may mean, most elengant,
most efficient, simplest, etc.

### Case study

Let's start with a very simple example: a stream of words (i.e. `String`s)
out of which a ranking by decreasing lengths should be created.
If we take the first paragraph of this document, i.e.

```
A common problem when processing data is to build 
a ranking of itemsbased on some property
```

we would get the following ranking (by inverse lengths) 
should be obtained:

```
1 - processing (10)
2 - property (8)
3 - problem (7)
3 - ranking (7)
5 - common (6)
6 - build (5)
6 - items (5)
6 - based (5)
9 - when (4)
9 - data (4)
9 - some (4)
12 - is (2)
12 - to (2)
12 - of (2)
12 - on (2)
16 - A (1)
16 - a (1)
```

When two items share the same ranking property value, they are assigned the same ranking.

### Questions

The main question here is:

> what stream API construct do you used to compute the ranking and how
>   you organize your code?

A second related question is

> how you represent the result of the ranking computation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two questions are addressed one after the other

- ranking representation
- ranking procedure

---

### Ranking representation

The typical ranking, as shown above, is a list of items preceded by their relative ranking value.

There are, at least, two possible implementations for the return value
of a ranking.

#### Option 1: `List<Rank>`

A possible internal representation of the ranking could be a list of
elements containing both the ranking value and the item. For instance
we could define a class:

```
public class Rank<T> {
  protected int ranking;
  protected T item;
  protected Rank(int r, T i) { ranking=t; item=i; }
  public int getRanking() { return ranking; }
  public T getItem() { return item; }
  static <T> Rank<T> factory(int ranking, T item) { 
      return new Rank<T>(ranking,item);
  }
}
```

Or, with a somewhat more esotheric code:

```
public interface Rank<T> {
      int getRanking();
      T getItem();
      static <T> Rank<T> factory(int ranking, T item) { 
          return new Rank<T>(){
               public int getRanking() { return ranking; }
               public T getItem() { return item; }
          };}
}
```

The resulting ranking will be returned as a `List<Rank>`.
The list must be returned sorted by descending ranking and processed in that order.

A potential disadvantage of such solution is the need for a new ad-hoc class or interface (i.e. `Rank`).

#### Option 2: `SortedMap<Integer,List<T>>`

An alternative solution that uses only predefined standard classes and intefaces is based on a map.

The keys of the map correspond to the ranking values, while the values of the map consist in lists that contain the items sharing that ranking.

The return type of the ranking would be a `SortedMap<T,List<T>>`.
The sorted map will be implicitly sorted and can be traversed according to the natural order of the key.

This latter solution seems preferable because it does not require any new class and can be better understood.

---

### Ranking Procedure

The ranking computation procedure can be implemented in different ways.
Here two approaches are examined.

In all cases we need to have a function that serves the purpose
of extracting the ranking property:

```
Function<String,Integer> propertyExtractor = String::length;
```

Typically, the property type should be comparable, though to be more general (e.g. to sort strings in decreasing order) the property comparator can be defined:

```
Comparator<Integer> propertyComparator = reverseOrder();
```

The two approaches are illustrated, referring to the case study described above, using a `words` stream as a starting point:

```
String paragraph = "A common problem when processing data is to build  a ranking of items based on some property";
Stream<String> words = Stream.of(paragraph.split(" "));
```

### Sorting by ranking property

#### Basic procedure

An initial naive version of the procedure can be defined using a supporting map data structure upon which the stream operations work by means of side effects:

```
SortedMap<Integer,List<String>> ranking = new TreeMap<>();
```

The procedure is as follows:

1. Sort the elements of the stream

   ```
   words.sorted(comparing(propetyExtractor,propertyComparator))
   ```
2. Assign the ranking, starting with `1` and incrementing it
   any time the property changes. The ranking has to be incremented
   by the number of items that shared the current ranking.

   ```
   .forEach( item -> {
       Integer property = propertyExtractor.apply(item);
       if(ranking.isEmpty()){
           ranking.put(1,new LinkedList<String>());
       }else{
           Integer rank = ranking.lastKey();
           List<String> items = ranking.get(rank);
           if(! property.equals(propertyExtractor.apply(items.get(0)))) {
               ranking.put(rank+items.size(), new LinkedList<String>());
           }
       }
       ranking.get(ranking.lastKey()).add(item);
   });
   ```

The above code works as follows:

- The initial sequence of items is unsorted:

  `{"DD","BBB","F","CCC","AAAA","EE"}`
- Step 1 sorts the item using the `propertyExtractor` and the relative `propertyComparator`, i.e. by string length:

  `{"AAAA","BBB","CCC","DD","EE","F"}`
- then for each element (in order) a new entry in the map is added
  any time the lenght of the new element differs from the previous
  element lenght

  - When `"AAAA"` is processed (first item) a new entry is added to
    the map with key (i.e. ranking) = 1:

    `ranking` : `{1=["AAAA"]}`
  - As the second item `"BBB"` is processed, since its lenght (3)
    is different from the last element length (4, the lenght of `"AAAA"`)
    a new entry is added with un updated ranking value:

    `ranking` : `{1=["AAAA"],2=["BBB"]}`
  - As the third item `"CCC"` is processed, since its lenght (3)
    is equal to the last element length, the item is added
    to the entry list

    `ranking` : `{1=["AAAA"],2=["BBB","CCC"]}`
  - etc.

#### Usage of collector

A more *functional-style* version can be defined by using a collector that encapsulates the data structure where the results are accumulated.
In practice we can write a single stream expression that returns the ranking map:

```
SortedMap<Integer,List<String>> ranking = 
words.sorted(comparing(propertyExtractor,propertyComparator))
     .collect(TreeMap::new, // supplier

             (rank, item) -> {  // accumulator
                 Integer property = propertyExtractor.apply(item);
                 if(rank.isEmpty()){
                     rank.put(1,new LinkedList<String>());
                 }else{
                     Integer r = rank.lastKey();
                     List<String> items = rank.get(r);
                     Integer prevProp = propertyExtractor.apply(items.get(0))
                     if(! property.equals(prevProp)) {
                         rank.put(r+items.size(), new LinkedList<String>());
                     }
                 }
                 rank.get(rank.lastKey()).add(item);
             },

             (rank1,rank2) -> { // combiner
                 \\...
             }
     );
```

#### Combining results

The *combiner* method that is left undefiened in the above code deserves some additional reflections.

The functional interface is involved when the collection is performed in parallel; it is used to combine two partial results of the accumulation into a single one. In this case, it has to implement the interface `BiConsumer<R,R>` and it is supposed to combine the two accumulated rankings - `rank1` and `rank2` - into the first one.

A possible implementation of the supplier is:

```
BiConsumer<SortedMap<Integer,List<String>>,
             SortedMap<Integer,List<String>>> combiner =  
(rank1,rank2) -> {
        int lastRanking = rank1.lastKey();
        int offset = lastRanking + rank1.get(lastRanking).size()-1;
        if( propertyExtractor.apply(rank1.get(lastRanking).get(0))
            == propertyExtractor.apply(rank2.get(rank2.firstKey()).get(0)) ){
            rank1.get(lastRanking).addAll(rank2.get(rank2.firstKey()));
            rank2.remove(rank2.firstKey());
        }
        rank2.forEach((r,items) -> {rank1.put(offset+r, items);} );
}
```

The collector has no declared properties, so the elements will be processed in order and then composed in order. E.g. the sorted list of items is divided into two parts, then the first part is processed through with one copy of the collector producing as result the map `rank1`; in parallel, the second part is processed giving as result `rank2`.

Let us suppose the streams are processed in parallel, in two concurent
execution of the collect operations:

- the initial sorted stream (result of the `sorted()` operation is
  divided into two stream, maintaining the orded

  - sub-stream 1: `{"AAAA","BBB","CCC"}`
  - sub-stream 2: `{"DD","EE","F"}`
- two distinct collectors operate in parallel, on each sub-stream
  the result are two maps contain the partial ranking of each sub-stream:

  - `rank1` = `{1=["AAAA"],2=["BBB","CCC"]}`
  - `rank2` = `{1=["DD","EE"],3=["F"]}`
- The *combiner* operation should merge `rank2` into `rank1`, in practice
  each entry of the `rank2` operation should be added to `rank1` with its
  key updated. They keys are updated by adding an offset that is equal to
  the key of the last entry plus the lenght of the last entry value list
  minus one:

  ```
  int lastRanking = rank1.lastKey();
  int offset = lastRanking + rank1.get(lastRanking).size()-1;
  ```

  In practice the entry `1=["DD","EE"]` of `rank2` should be turned into
  `4=["DD","EE"]` and added to `rank1`.
- In addition, a special case should be considered, i.e. when the items
  in the last entry of `rank1` and those in the first entry of `rank2`
  share the same ranking property value. E.g. for string length:

  - `rank1` = `{1=["AAAA"],2=["BBB","CCC"]}`
  - `rank2` = `{1=["DDD"],2=["EE"],3=["F"]}`

  When this case occurs, the items in the `rank2` first entry list
  must be added to this in the last `rank1` entry list, and then the
  first entry removed.
  That is the above maps should be transformed into:

  - `rank1` = `{1=["AAAA"],2=["BBB","CCC"`**`,"DDD"`**`]}`
  - `rank2` = `{`~~`1=["DDD"],`~~`2=["EE"],3=["F"]}`

  Then the entries of `rank2` can be updated and added to `rank1` as
  described above.

### Grouping by ranking property

#### Basic procedure

As for the sorted list version, an initial naive version of the procedure can be defined using a supporting map data structure upon which the stream operations work by means of side effects:

```
SortedMap<Integer,List<String>> ranking = new TreeMap<>();
```

The naive procedure is as follows:

1. group the items by their property in a sorted map

   ```
   words.collect(groupingBy(propertyExtractor,
                           ()->new TreeMap<>(propertyComparator),toList()))
   ```
2. for each entry in the above map compute the ranking

   ```
        .forEach(
           (property,items) -> 
               ranking.put(ranking.isEmpty()?1:ranking.lastKey()+
                                   ranking.get(ranking.lastKey()).size(),
                           items )
                );
   ```

The above code works as follows:

- The initial sequence of items is unsorted:

  `{"DD","BBB","F","CCC","AAAA","EE"}`
- Step 1 groups the item by their `propertyExtractor` and store them into
  a sorted set whose keys are sorted through the `propertyComparator`, i.e.
  by string length:

  `{4=["AAAA"],3=["BBB","CCC"],2=["DD","EE"],1=["F"]}`
- Step 2, creates for each entry in the intermediate map a new entry in
  the result map have the ranking value as key and the same value (i.e.
  the list of items) as the intermediate entry.

  The ranking is computed as follows:

  - 1 for the first entry (i.e. when the result map is still empty), or
  - previous ranking (`ranking.lastKey()`) plus number of elements
    sharing the previous ranking (`ranking.get(ranking.lastKey()).size()`).

  The result is the final ranking map:

  `{1=["AAAA"],2=["BBB","CCC"],4=["DD","EE"],6=["F"]}`

#### Using a collector

The above procedure can be rewritten using a collector to avoid side effects of the operations.

Since the first step consists in a collection, we can use the predefined collector factory methdo `collectingAndThen` to concatenate the first collector with a function that is applied to the collector result;
such a function will perform the step 2 described above.

```
SortedMap<Integer,List<String>> ranking = 
words.collect(
       collectingAndThen(
            groupingBy(propertyExtractor, 
                         ()->new TreeMap<>(propertyComparator),
                         toList()),
            map -> map.entrySet().stream().collect(
                      TreeMap::new,
                      (rank,entry) -> 
                          rank.put(rank.isEmpty()?1:rank.lastKey()+ 
                                        rank.get(rank.lastKey()).size(),
                                 entry.getValue() ),
                      combiner 
                    )
        )
);
```

Since the structure of the result, i.e. the accumulator object, is the
same as the sorted stream solution, here the same combiner can be used.

### Generic solutions

The above discussion and solution applied to the special case of 
a stream of Strings. But the approach can be generalized using generics.

### Ranking sorting function

The solution based on the sorted stream can be enclosed in a function:

```
static <T,V> SortedMap<Integer,List<T>> 
rank(Stream<T> stream, 
     Function<T,V> propertyExtractor, 
     Comparator<V> propertyComparator){
  return
  stream.sorted(comparing(propertyExtractor,propertyComparator))
        .collect(TreeMap::new, 
                 (rank, item) -> {
                    V property = propertyExtractor.apply(item);
                    if(rank.isEmpty()){
                      rank.put(new Integer(1),new LinkedList<T>());
                    }else{
                      Integer r = rank.lastKey();
                      List<T> items = rank.get(r);
                      if(! property.equals(propertyExtractor.apply(items.get(0)))) {
                        rank.put(r+items.size(), new LinkedList<T>());
                      }
                    }
                    rank.get(rank.lastKey()).add(item);
                },
            (rank1,rank2) -> { 
                   int lastRanking = rank1.lastKey();
                   int offset = lastRanking + rank1.get(lastRanking).size()-1;
                   if( propertyExtractor.apply(rank1.get(lastRanking).get(0))
                       == propertyExtractor.apply(rank2.get(rank2.firstKey()).get(0))){
                     rank1.get(lastRanking).addAll(rank2.get(rank2.firstKey()));
                     rank2.remove(rank2.firstKey());
                   }
                   rank2.forEach((r,items) -> {rank1.put(offset+r, items);} );
            }
    );
}
```

The above method can be applied as:

```
SortedMap<Integer,List<String>> ranking =
            rank(words,String::length,reverseOrder());
```

### Ranking grouping collector

The approach based on the grouping by property value can be
encapsulated in a collector:

```
static <T,V> Collector<T,?,SortedMap<Integer,List<T>>> 
rankingCollector(Function<T,V> propertyExtractor, 
                 Comparator<V> propertyComparator){
  return 
  collectingAndThen(
    groupingBy(propertyExtractor,
               ()->new TreeMap<>(propertyComparator),
               toList()),
    map -> map.entrySet().stream().collect(
            TreeMap::new,
            (rank,entry) -> 
                  rank.put(rank.isEmpty()?1:rank.lastKey()+
                             rank.get(rank.lastKey()).size(),
                           entry.getValue() ),
            (rank1,rank2) -> { 
                   int lastRanking = rank1.lastKey();
                   int offset = lastRanking + rank1.get(lastRanking).size()-1;
                   if( propertyExtractor.apply(rank1.get(lastRanking).get(0))
                       == 

    propertyExtractor.apply(rank2.get(rank2.firstKey()).get(0))){
                         rank1.get(lastRanking).addAll(rank2.get(rank2.firstKey()));
                         rank2.remove(rank2.firstKey());
                       }
                       rank2.forEach((r,items) -> {rank1.put(offset+r, items);} );
                }
         )
      );
    }
```

This collector factory method can be used e.g. as:

```
SortedMap<Integer,List<String>> ranking =
        words.collect(rankingCollector(String::length,reverseOrder()));
```

### Printing the ranking

Once the ranking has been computed and stored in the map, it can be printed,  typically for debug purposes.

Here are a few possible options for printing the ranking on the console.

### Printer `Consumer`

Using a consumer object that takes the ranking, format the entries
and print them.
The following code reports a factory method the returns
such a consumer:

```
static <T,V> Consumer<Map<Integer,List<T>>> 
rankPrinter(Function<T,V> propertyExtractor){
      return ranking ->
       ranking.entrySet().stream()
       .map( e -> e.getValue().stream().map( 
                   v -> e.getKey() + " - " + v 
                       + " (" + propertyExtractor.apply(v) + ")" ) )
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

#### Collator `Function`

Using a function that transform the ranking map into
a string consisting in the concatenation of the items.

```
static <T,V> Function<Map<Integer,List<T>>,String> 
rankCollator(Function<T,V> propertyExtractor){
  return ranking ->         
        ranking.entrySet().stream()
                .map( e -> (Stream<String>)e.getValue().stream().
                        map( v -> (String)(e.getKey() + " : " + v + " (" + propertyExtractor.apply(v) + ")") ))
                        .flatMap(Function.identity())
                        .collect(joining("\n"));
    }
```

The above method can be used as follows:

```
System.out.println(rankCollator(propertyExtractor).apply(ranking));
```

#### Ranking `Map` class

As an alternative, is is possible to replace the class `TreeMap`
with a new class that extends it and overrides the `toString()`
method.

This cane be done by writing the following collector accumulator
supplier, instead of `TreeMap::new`:

```
()->new TreeMap<Integer,List<T>>(){
    public String toString(){
        return entrySet().stream()
                .map( e -> (Stream<String>)e.getValue().stream().map( 
                            v -> e.getKey().toString() + " - " + v.toString() 
                                    + " (" + propertyExtractor.apply(v) + ")" ) )
                .flatMap(Function.identity())
                .collect(joining("\n")); 
    }
}
```

The complete code for the generics solution is available in class 
[StreamRanking](https://github.com/mtorchiano/JavaUtilities/blob/master/src/it/polito/utility/stream/Ranking.java) available on my github repo.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike solved by yourself by **Design First** I doing it via [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) way.

### Step 1, assuming there is only one word exists.

let's say ranking `"foo"` will represented as `["1 - foo (3)"]`,I solved it by using [Stream.map(Function)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and **fake** the rank with constant `1`.

```
Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
      .map(it -> String.format("%d - %s (%d)", 1, it, it.length()))
      .collect(toList());
```

### Step 2, assuming there are 2 words that their length are the same.

let's say ranking `"foo bar"` will represented as `["1 - bar (3)","1 - foo (3)"]`. I solved it by  [Stream.sorted(Comparator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-);

```
Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
      .sorted(String::compareTo)
      .map(it -> String.format("%d - %s (%d)", 1, it, it.length()))
      .collect(toList());
```

### Step 3, assuming there are 2 words that their length are different.

let's say ranking `"fuzz bar"` will represented as `["1 - fuzz (4)","2 - bar (3)"]`,I solved it by [Comparator.comparing(Function)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-).

```
Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed()
                        .thenComparing(String::compareTo))
      .map(it -> String.format("%d - %s (%d)", 1, it, it.length()))
      .collect(toList());
```

the result ["1 - fuzz (4)","1~~2~~ - bar (3)"] are the same except the faked rank constant `1`.so I do a small refactoring before change code:

```
Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed()
                        .thenComparing(String::compareTo))
      .map(it -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(1,it))
      .map(it -> String.format("%d - %s (%d)", it.getKey(), it.getValue(), it.getValue().length()))
      .collect(toList());
```

then I can replace the first [Stream.map(Function)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) with [Stream.collect(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-).stream() and replace the faked rank constant `1` with `ranking.size() + 1`.

```
Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed()
                        .thenComparing(String::compareTo))
      .collect(ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>::new
              , (ranking, it) -> ranking.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(ranking.size() + 1, it))
              , List::addAll).stream()
      .map(it -> String.format("%d - %s (%d)", it.getKey(), it.getValue(), it.getValue().length()))
      .collect(toList());
```

but the **Step 2** broked due to `rank = ranking.size() + 1`; then I realized I need comparing its length with the last ranking item.

```
BiConsumer<List<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>, String> accumulator = (ranking, it) -> {
    int rank = ranking.size() + 1;
    if (!ranking.isEmpty()) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, String> last = ranking.get(ranking.size() - 1);
        if (last.getValue().length() == it.length()) {
            rank = last.getKey();
        }
    }
    ranking.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(rank, it));
};

List<String> ranking = Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed()
                          .thenComparing(String::compareTo))
        .collect(ArrayList::new, accumulator, List::addAll).stream()
        .map(it -> String.format("%d - %s (%d)", it.getKey(), it.getValue(), it.getValue().length()))
        .collect(toList());
```

Indeed, I find I can replace an ArrayList with a Stack in further:

```
BiConsumer<Stack<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>, String> accumulator = (ranking, it) -> {
    int rank = ranking.size() + 1;
    if (!ranking.isEmpty()) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, String> last = ranking.peek();
        if (last.getValue().length() == it.length()) {
            rank = last.getKey();
        }
    }
    ranking.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(rank, it));
};

List<String> ranking = Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed()
                          .thenComparing(String::compareTo))
        .collect(Stack::new, accumulator, List::addAll).stream()
        .map(it -> String.format("%d - %s (%d)", it.getKey(), it.getValue(), it.getValue().length()))
        .collect(toList());
```

### Fix a bug by introduce another test

After finishing the code, I found there is a bug existed in the code. let's say ranking `"fuzz buzz foo"` will represented as `["1 - buzz (4)","1 - fuzz (4)","2 - foo (3)"]`, I solved it by calculate rank as `last.rank + 1` rather than `ranking.size() + 1`.

```
BiConsumer<Stack<Entry<Integer, String>>, String> accumulator = (ranking, it) -> {
    int rank;
    if (!ranking.isEmpty()) {
        Entry<Integer, String> last = ranking.peek();
        if (last.getValue().length() == it.length()) {
            rank = last.getKey();
        } else {
            rank = last.getKey() + 1;
        }
    } else {
        rank = 1;
    }
    ranking.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(rank, it));
};

List<String> ranking = Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
        .sorted(comparing(String::length).reversed()
               .thenComparing(String::compareTo))
        .collect(Stack::new, accumulator, List::addAll).stream()
        .map(it -> format("%d - %s (%d)", it.getKey(), it.getValue(), it.getValue().length()))
        .collect(toList());
```

### Finally

I rename variable `accumulator` with a meaningful name, e.g:`rankingEvaluation`, and replace `null` with [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), and .etc.

```
Map.Entry<Integer, String> NONE = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(0, "");

BiConsumer<Stack<Entry<Integer, String>>, String> rankingEvaluation = (ranking, it) -> {
    Entry<Integer, String> last = ranking.isEmpty() ? NONE : ranking.peek();
    int rank = last.getValue().length() == it.length() 
                                         ? last.getKey() 
                                         : last.getKey() + 1;
    ranking.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(rank, it));
};

List<String> ranking = Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
        .sorted(comparing(String::length).reversed()
               .thenComparing(String::compareTo))
        .collect(Stack::new, rankingEvaluation, List::addAll).stream()
        .map(it -> format("%d - %s (%d)", it.getKey(), it.getValue(), it.getValue().length()))
        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Nice presentation of how a solution can be developed.